# Does there exist a polynomial sequence $P_n$ satisfying this?

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Rudin - RCA p.276 exercise 3

> Does there exist a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $P_n(0)=1$ for $n=1,2,...$, but $P_n(z)\rightarrow 0$ for every $z\neq 0$, as $n\to \infty$?

The chapter this exercise is included is about Runge's Theorem. However, Runge's Theorem gives no information about pointwise convergence, so I think it is true. But I have a trouble constructing one. How do I prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $0 < r < R < +\infty$ and $0 < \varepsilon < +\infty$, let

$$A(r,R,\varepsilon) := \{ \rho \cdot e^{i\varphi} : r \leqslant \rho \leqslant R, \varepsilon \leqslant \varphi \leqslant 2\pi - \varepsilon\}.$$

For $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0,1\}$, let

$$K_n = \{0\} \cup e^{i/n}\cdot A\bigl(\tfrac{1}{n},n,\tfrac{1}{n+1}\bigr).$$

$\mathbb{C}\setminus K_n$ is connected for all $n$, and the function

$$f_n \colon z \mapsto \begin{cases}1 &, z = 0 \\ 0 &, z \in K_n\setminus\{0\} \end{cases}$$

is holomorphic on $K_n$ (i.e., it's the restriction to $K_n$ of a holomorphic function defined on some open neighbourhood of $K_n$), so by Runge's theorem there is a polynomial $Q_n$ such that for all $z \in K_n$ we have $\lvert Q_n(z) - f_n(z)\rvert \leqslant 2^{-n}$. Let $P_n(z) = Q_n(z)/Q_n(0)$, then $P_n(0) = 1$ and $\lvert P_n(z) - f_n(z)\rvert \leqslant 2^{1-n}$ for all $z\in K_n$.

Since every $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus 0$ belongs to $K_n$ for all large enough $n$, it follows that the sequence $(P_n)$ has the desired properties.

Comment: Thank you. But what's the role of $e^{i/n}$ here? (Rotating annulus) why do wr need that?

Comment: If we didn't move the slit, we couldn't ensure that $P_n(z) \to 0$ for $z$ in the slit. We need a sequence of compact sets $K_n$ such that for every $z$ there is an $n(z)$ such that $z \in K_n$ for all $n \geqslant n(z)$ to guarantee the pointwise convergence.

Comment: You could also let $K_n = \{0\} \cup A_n,$ where $A_n = \{re^{it}: r\in [1/n,n], t \in [0,2\pi - 1/n]\}.$

Comment: It might be trivial, but I don't see how do you get the last inequality $|P_n(z)-f_n(z)|\leq 2^{1-n}$.

Comment: @Emin For $z = 0$ we have $P_n(0) = f_n(0)$, and for $z \in K_n \setminus \{0\}$ we have $$\lvert P_n(z) - f_n(z)\rvert = \lvert P_n(z)\rvert = \lvert Q_n(0)\rvert^{-1}\cdot \lvert Q_n(z)\rvert = \lvert Q_n(0)\rvert^{-1}\lvert Q_n(z) - f_n(z)\rvert < \lvert Q_n(0)\rvert^{-1}\cdot 2^{-n}.$$ And $\lvert Q_n(0) - f_n(0)\rvert = \lvert Q_n(0) - 1\rvert < 2^{-n}$ implies $\lvert Q_n(0)\rvert > 1 - 2^{-n} \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$, hence $\lvert Q_n(0)\rvert^{-1} \leqslant 2$.